# EditText операции над введенным текстом

Tags: android, java

Привет.

Надо провести операции над введенным текстом. 
Допустим, у меня есть массив  `double [] arr`  со значениями. Пользователь вводит в EditText переменные в формате: "А1, А2, А7, А5" и т.д.

Дальше надо как-то, исходя из введенных переменных, сложить переменные из массива. 
То есть `double summ = arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[7]+arr[5];`.

Каким методом это можно сделать?

Comment: ты уже ответил на свой вопрос.
`double summ = arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[7]+arr[5]; `

Comment: Как элементы в массиве суммировать, я знаю. Меня интересовал вопрос, как сделать это по маске, введенной в EditText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Достаете текст из EditText .
2. Вырезаете в  полученной строке все символы " "(пробел) и ",", получаете строку, состоящую из A и цифр.
3. Разделяете строку на массив строк по символу "A".
4. Преобразуете каждый из элементов массива из строк в числа.
5. Берете нужные индексы массива arr.

Comment: То есть, грубо говоря, у меня будет массив, допустим, chars, c индексами массива arr и сложение делаю как-то так: 

    int [] chars = {1,2,7,5}; // массив с индексами, сделанный из строки
    double [] arr = {0.1, 3,5, 0,6, 3, 65, 0,111}; //мой массив со значениями
    int summ = arr[chars[0]]+arr[chars[1]]+arr[chars[2]]+arr[chars[3]] 
да?

Comment: @yuga92 тебе это всё надо парсить. Double.parseDouble или Integer.parseInt. каждый элемент. См. пункт 4.